# How to know if predictive keyboard is ON/OFF in iOS8?

Tags: xcode, ios8, uikeyboard

anybody know how to verify if predictive keyboard (https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/quicktype/) is ON/OFF in user settings?

I need to reposition my view according to the keyboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should observe `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`. The value of the key `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` will contain the frame of the keyboard regardless of its layout.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm using this already but wasn't looking at the CGRect containing the frame of keyboard with predictive bar. Thanks!